# pytrends from behind the proxy

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, connection

I have python 3.6 and pytrends installed on Windows 8 machine behind corporate proxy. When running pytrend.build_payload(), adapters.py raises connection error (`No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`)

I can specify proxy as a variable like

```
 proxies = {
    'http': 'http://user:pass@address:port',
    'https': 'http://user:pass@address:port',
}
```

but how then I can make pytrends use it?

Answer (score 1):

[Forked version of pytrends.request](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/commit/63cbadd3c46d5e2a03f7c5ce0c369225c86c6bc9) can work over proxy:

https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/pytrends/request.py